# Flutter: Rendering working fine on android device but overflowing on iOS device of a different size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

From the AppWidget (home of the material app), I am returning a GridView. Below is the code of AppWidget's build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBarWidget(widget.title),
  body: SafeArea(
          child: GridView.count(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
        mainAxisSpacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
        children: List.generate(workoutList.length, (index) {
          return WorkoutOverviewWidget(workoutList[index]);
        })),
  ),
);
```

}

Below is the code for WorkoutOverviewWidget's build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return InkWell(
  splashColor: Colors.black,
  onTap: () => gotoWorkoutDetailsWidget(context),
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    child: Container(
      height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
              MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
              kToolbarHeight) *
          (0.30),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (0.4),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  getWorkoutImagePath(this._workout.type),
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
                          kToolbarHeight) *
                      (0.225),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                right: 10,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Text(
                    Utils.getEnumName(this._workout.type.toString()),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
                    kToolbarHeight) *
                (0.015),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 4,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today_rounded,
                size: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 3,
              ),
              Utils.displayText(
                text: getReadableTimestamp(this._workout.timestamp),
                allPadding: 5,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontFamily:
                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.fontFamily,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

I have used MediaQuery to avoid hardcoding the size of any widget. The code is working fine when I tested it on the Google Pixel emulator but overflows on iPhone 12 Max Pro emulator. Below are the screenshots:

Output on Google Pixel emulator:

[image: Output on Google Pixel emulator]

Output on iPhone 12 Max Pro emulator:

[image: Output on iPhone 12 Max Pro emulator]

What is the thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by not defining the height of the image in ClipRRect explicitly but instead wrapping them in the Expanded() widget with flex property defined to adjust the percentage of height distributed between the children in column. Updated code for WorkoutOverviewWidget's build method:

```
return InkWell(
  splashColor: Colors.black,
  onTap: () => gotoWorkoutDetailsWidget(context),
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    child: Container(
      height: this._availableHeight * (0.30),
      width: this._screenWidth * (0.4),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    getWorkoutImagePath(this._workout.type),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 10,
                  right: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Text(
                      Utils.getEnumName(this._workout.type.toString()),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: this._screenWidth * (0.02),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.calendar_today_rounded,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: this._screenWidth * (0.01),
                ),
                Utils.displayText(
                  text: getReadableTimestamp(this._workout.timestamp),
                  allPadding: 5,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontFamily:
                      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.fontFamily,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MediaQuery is a good first step, but this will adjust your dimensions according to the screen, but if those dimensions are bigger than their parent, they will over Flow.
Wrap your sized box with an Expanded, wrap your Last Row with an expanded also, and it's children, which are overflowing [children of row] in an expanded], the overflow will go away, then you can readjust the heights as you want. It has nothing to do with android or iOS, it's only related to the dimensions of the screens you are using. It can overflow on an android device with similar device dimensions as the one you are using for iOS. Try it out, it would solve your problem.

Comment: I was thinking if `overflow:hidden` and `min-height:` in mediaquery will fix that issue.

Comment: You need to identify what is overflowing first. What is overflowing in your case? Did you find it?

Comment: You are hiding text overflow, but about the containers below it?

Comment: I agree it's an issue related to screen size and not OS but in the code, the container has a height of 0.3 times the available height and the image is given 0.225 times the available height and the same for the sized box which is 0.015 times. Now, since all the dimensions are given relative to the available height, how come it is overflowing for one screen size but not another? In fact shouldn't this behaviour be the opposite like iOS device has more height than the android one so the remaining height for the bottom-most row is more in iOS, so android one should overflow, right?